# How to group chrome extensions icons on toolbar?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, toolbar

Is there a way to group Chrome extensions icons in some kind of different organized folders?

For example, a folder named "form tools" would open a dropdown list giving access to several different extensions to autofill forms; another folder would give access to responsive tools.

Comment: One main icon + browserAction popup is the only method.

Comment: There is not surprisingly a chrome extension called Context that allows you to organize your extensions into groups and name them what you want. I have used it for years and its great. Check it out in the Web Store.

Comment: [Context](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context/aalnjolghjkkogicompabhhbbkljnlka) extension mentioned above is an example of using browserAction popup + chrome.management API.

Comment: Thanks. I already saw Context, and it'll do the job; the Perfect solution would have been having groups right on chrome toolbar, and each extension triggered in just 2 clicks (Context requires 3 clicks: one to open dropdown, one to open group and last to trigger extension). If any better solution exists someday, if someone has the idea to develop it ...

Comment: @wOxxOm Context is no more on Chrome's webstore.

Comment: @aderchox even if not on the Chrome's webstore I just installed it on Brave and it works. It can be done on Chrome as well, by activating Dev mode and loading the unzipped extension release found in GitHub.